# PyGame Не обрабатываются события pygame.KEYDOWN

Tags: python, pygame

Создал файл, инициализировал `pygame`, создал окошко и класс игрока. в обработке событий был краток, задал всего три. выход из игры, который работает, и перемещение влево-вправо, которые были заданы в классе плэйер, но не работают. создал объект, который по идее должен был наследовать все методы и аттрибуты, закинул в `sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()`, а в игровом цикле записал обновление `sprites.update` и отрисовку `sprites.draw`. рисуется(то есть один метод работает), но не управляется.

Вот собственно тот самый код:

```
pygame.init()                                                   
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W_Width, W_Height)
background = pygame.image.load('background_of_game.jpg'
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
#Класс Игрока
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.PositionX = 0
        self.PositionY = 463
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Прямо1.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.PositionX, self.PositionY)
        self.SpeedX = 0
        self.SpeedY = 0
        self.Right = False
        self.Left = False

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for k in keys:
            if k == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.Right = True
            if k == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.Left = True
        if self.Right:
            self.SpeedX = 5
        if self.Left:
            self.SpeedX = -5
        if not Left or Right:
            self.SpeedX = 0
        self.PositionX += self.SpeedX
        self.PositionY += self.SpeedY
        if self.rect.right > W_Width:
            self.rect.right = W_Width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (PositionX, PositionY))


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

#Игровой Цикл
runGame = True
while runGame:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runGame = False
    
    all_sprites.update()
    timer.tick(FPS)
    screen.blit(background, [0, 0])
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть код

Comment: Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Comment: Добавил голос за закрытие, т.к. приведенное описание и код не MCVE. Судя по ответам, там или опечатка, или достаточно фрагмента обработки нажатия кнопок.

Answer (score 3):

Кажется у вас скобочка не закрыта на 3й строке где вы бэкграунд задаете.

Также, я не советую вам кириллицу использовать. Какая-то ОС может офигеть от такой наглости, поэтому советую писать все на английском языке.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правильно проверяете нажатие клавиш

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
for k in keys:
    if k == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.Right = True
    if k == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.Left = True
```

замените на

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.Right = True
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.Left = True
```

Comment: этот ответ на самом деле правильный